# Understanding ARM Cortex-M0+ relocation

Tags: arm, relocation

I'm just getting started with embedded arm development, and there's a snippet of code that's really bugging me:

```c
/* Initialize the relocate segment */
pSrc = &_etext;
pDest = &_srelocate;

if (pSrc != pDest) 
{
    while (pDest < &_erelocate) 
    {
        *pDest++ = *pSrc++;
    }
}
```

Where `_etext` and `_srelocate` are symbols defined in the linker script:

```
. = ALIGN(4);
_etext = .;

.relocate : AT (_etext)
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate = .;
    *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
    *(.data .data.*);
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate = .;
} > ram
```

Where `ram` is a memory segment whose origin is `0x20000000`. The issue as I see it is that `_etext` is a symbol that marks the end boundary of the `.text` segment, which is a part of a different memory segment, `rom`. This means that unless the aforementioned memory segment was 100% full, `_etext != _srelocate` will always be true. What this means is that we're copying memory beyond the `.text` section where nothing is defined to live according to the linker script.

To me, this leads to one of three scenarios, either A) There is garbage present in `rom` beyond the `.text` section, and it gets copied into `.relocate` (and subsequently `.data`), or B) The memory beyond `.text` is empty following a chip erase operation prior to device programming, in which case `.relocate` is zeroed, or C) There is some slight of hand magic happening here where `.data` values are placed after `.text` in `rom`, and must be loaded into `ram`; in which case the comment should be `s/relocate/data`.

The third scenario seems the most likely, but according to the linker script this can't be true. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: You're right, it's the third option. The AT() tells the linker to put the .ramfunc and .data sections (both of which are read/write) in the object file starting at _etext. The "> ram" tells the linker to resolve relocations as if the sections were placed in RAM. The result is that the copy loop moves the data from the read only area to the read/write area when the program starts up.

Comment: @RichardPennington Awesome, do you think you could add this in the form of an answer, possibly with a quote from the ld manual which covers the `AT()` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it's the third option. The **AT()** tells the linker to put the **.ramfunc** and **.data** sections (both of which are read/write) in the object file starting at **_etext**. The "> ram" tells the linker to resolve relocations as if the sections were placed in RAM this is done using a MEMORY command as decribed here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html#MEMORY The result is that the copy loop moves the data from the read only area to the read/write area when the program starts up.

Here's a link to the gnu ld documentation where controlling the LMA (load address) is described: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html